Azure DevOps - Releases - Dynamics Lifecycle Services (LCS) Asset Deployment - Error in request to deploy file asset
My automated release fails when trying to apply a package to an environment using 'Dynamics Lifecycle Services (LCS) Asset Deployment'

Error string: Error in request to deploy file asset: 'You don't have the required permissions to perform this operation.'

Error log:

I have checked and rechecked everything several times.

The service user is a Project owner in LCS and can log in and apply packages
The service user does not have MFA
The app reg is set up and checked again
The LCS Service user is added to security of the agent pool as an admin

It is also strange that the previous step "Dynamics Lifecycle Services (LCS) Asset Upload" is working, this means it is connecting successfully and I do have permission to upload a package to LCS, so no issue with connection / service connection / app reg / permission.
Successful package upload:

Dynamics Lifecycle Services (LCS) Asset Deployment setup:

(I have tried changing the tasks)
I have gone into pipeline security and made sure the service user and the build service have permissions to Manage releases and deployments.
(this is being tested via the create release option using an admin account)
Any help would be greatly appreciated

The Azure DevOps pipeline must be run by a user with the Environment manager role in the corresponding Dynamics Lifecycle Services project.

Hi thank you for your response.
My user has Project Owner Role, the administrator user used to create and test the Release has Project Owner and the LCS service account used for the LCS Service connection has Project Owner.
Also the upload asset to LCS is working, so I know the LCS service connection is working / the service user can connect and upload assets/packages to LCS.
It feels like it is trying to use a user other than those three mentioned above.

It still looks like a permission issue. You may check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/pipeline-deploy-asset for more details.

'LCS File Asset Id' in the image above is using the 'Asset Name' and not the 'Asset ID', go to LCS Asset library select a package and you can see an example of Id vs Name.
There are additional steps required:

in the upload Asset step there is an additional section for "Output Variables", expand that, in 'Reference name' add: Upload

You have now created a variable that captures and holds the Asset Id

In the LCS File Asset Id of the asset deployment step add exactly like this: $(Upload.FileAssetId)

That resolved the error and started the deployment.
